# How to adjust margin in ggarrange ggpubr ggplot (axis elements disappear) R

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I want to stack 3 plots into 1 using `ggarrange` but the x-axis elements (dates) of the bottom plot are always disappeared.

For example, here axis elements of `plot_3` (Z) are missing.

```
ggarrange(plot_1, plot_2, plot_3 + rremove("x.text"), 
          nrow = 3, align = "h")
```

[image: Result 1]

And when I change the order, axis elements of `plot_2`(Y) are now disappeared.

```
ggarrange(plot_1, plot_3, plot_2 + rremove("x.text"), 
          nrow = 3, align = "h")
```

[image: Result 2]

I tried to adjust the margins in each `ggplot`, but the same problem persists. So, I guess it must be something to do with the margins in `ggarrange` .

By the way, I also tried to remove all the x-axis title of the first two plots, and keep the title of the last (bottom) plot, but again, the dates are still missing.

Comment: but are you not removing them with `rremove("x.text")`

Comment: ps see [egg::ggarrange](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/egg/vignettes/Overview.html) if you also want the panels to align

Comment: Right! How could I missed that?!!

Answer (score 6):

I think that the function theme() would be useful

```
ggarrange(plot_1, plot_2, plot_3 + rremove("x.text"), 
          nrow = 3, align = "h")+
  theme(plot.margin = margin(0.1,0.1,2,0.1, "cm"))
```